# ruby - check if either of two variables exist

Tags: ruby, vagrantfile

I need to check if either of two environment variables env_http_proxy or http_proxy are set. If either is set, assign the value to a local variable. If neither of them exist, then the local variable should be set to nil.

```
http_proxy = defined?(ENV['env_http_proxy']) ? ENV['env_http_proxy'] : defined?(ENV['http_proxy']) ? ENV['http_proxy'] : nil
```

Whats wrong with this? this seem to work for the first variable but not for the second variable.
(PS: If it matters, I am trying to use this in a Vagrantfile)

Also, can someone please explain the above syntax. I am ruby noob. A quick search only showed the [defined?()](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) function. But  not the above extended syntax.

Comment: I think you can use something like: `http_proxy = ENV['env_http_proxy'] || ENV['http_proxy'] || nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = ENV['env_http_proxy'] || ENV['http_proxy']
```

As a general rule, don't use `defined?` for anything.  It's a metaprogramming primitive intended for implementing something occasionally called *magic*<sup>1.</sup>.

The `e1 ? e2 : e3` operator works just like C, testing expression e1 and then taking the value of e2 or e3.  It's not used as much in Ruby as in other languages.

Since ENV is a hash-like object, it will return `nil` when no key exists, and one of the zillion awesome features of Ruby is the way the `||` operator returns the value of the true expression.

---

<sup>1. *Magic*: noun, see: [Ruby on Rails.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails)</sup>